# Expanding logarithm of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is there a way (there has to be), I can expand an expression like this?

$$\log_2 (3f(n)^n)$$

P.S. This part of an assignment I'm working on, please do not give solutions

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?   Find an inverse function to?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solve'? If 'expand', then yes, there is a way

Comment: I probably worded the question wrong. The actual question says compute. https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/tandy/big-oh.pdf Q5

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:
$$\log_c(A\cdot B) = \log_c(A) + \log_c(B)$$
$$\log_c(D^n) = n\log_c(D)$$
Then, if $A=3$, $B = f(n)^n$ ... what can be made of 
$$\log_2\left(3f(n)^n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the properties of **log**.
They can be found all over the web (...and in many books too).